# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have query I'm calculating the dates but getting an error:

```
SELECT  
    (100 / (DATEDIFF(DAY, 01-02-2018, 31-07-2018) * DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), 01-02-2018) / 100)
FROM
    TansiqProjectData
```

GETTING THIS Error now:

> (Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.)

```
SELECT (100/(DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(datetime,'2018-02-01 00:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime,'2018-07-31 23:59:59.9999999')) * (GETDATE()-CONVERT(datetime,'2018-02-01 00:00:00'))/100));
```

Comment: It's probably because there's a missing `)`. The rest of the query is wrong though - `31-07-2018` isn't a date string , it's two subtractions. You *shouldn't* store or pass dates as strings anyway, use datet-typed columns, variables and parameters. If you *have* to use a date literal (ie string), use the `YYYYMMDD` form. Any other form is affected by the server's local.

Comment: Date literals as string **must be** in **single quotes!** Use `DATEDIFF(DAY, '01-02-2018', '31-07-2018')`. Also: to avoid any settings-related problems, I'd **strongly recommend** using the (adapted) **ISO-8601** date format for string literals : `YYYYMMDD` (in that format - *without* any dashes etc.)

Comment: still same eeor

Comment: Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: SELECT  
    (100 / (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-02-01', '2018-07-31') * DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), '2018-02-01') / 100)
)

Answer (score 0):

In your first select statement missing `)` braket at end.

In Second Statement you trying to multiply date with integer which is not allowed.

`(GETDATE()-CONVERT(datetime,'2018-02-01 00:00:00')` this returns date as result and you are trying to multiply with `datediff(day,date,date)` which is integer.

Comment: No still getting error Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: SELECT (100/(DATEDIFF(DAY,'2018-02-01','2018-07-31' ) * 
(GETDATE()-CONVERT(datetime,'2018-02-01 00:00:00'))/100))

;

Comment: `Select (DATEDIFF(DAY,'2018-02-01','2018-07-31' )) `=> result integer  AND                     
`select (GETDATE()-CONVERT(datetime,'2018-02-01 00:00:00'))` =>  result date    and You are trying to multiply which is not allowed in sql server

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not provide simple 01-02-2018 value to the argument of DATEDIFF method. You have to covered the value with single quote (') as '01-02-2018'.

Second, the provided value inside single code has to be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

So the Overall query should be as below-

```
SELECT  
(
    100 
    / 
    (
        (
            DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-02-01', '2018-07-31') 
            *    
            DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(),'2018-02-01') 
        )
        / 
        100
    )
)
FROM
TansiqProjectData
```